# angularjs with nodejs the ng-repeat doesn´t work

Tags: angularjs, node.js, socket.io, angularjs-ng-repeat

This is my angular code http://pastebin.com/e0SGX9mX
and this is my HTML http://pastebin.com/Mc6DHzks
and this is the node code

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);

var io = require('socket.io')(http);

var fs = require('fs');

var users = [];

io.on('connection', function(server) {

        server.on('join', function(name) {

        server.nickname = name;

        server.broadcast.emit('add chatter', server.nickname);
        //client.emit('messages', messages);

        console.log(server.nickname + ' join to chat ... ');
        });

    server.on('disconnect', function () {
        server.broadcast.emit('user disconnected', server.nickname);
    });

});

http.listen(8080);
```

My Problem when i fired the event "add chatter" the user doesn´t show in the li list with the `ng-repeat`. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `$scope.$digest();` to your add chatter method. Changes you make your scope are not monitored if they are asynchronous.

Comment: No problem. Mark this solution as the answer.